# SQL SERVER Can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un insert simple y me encuentro con este error.

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'alumnos_' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Este es mi query

```
USE [hero16c41959ed8b28]
GO
CREATE TABLE alumnos_ (
  [id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
  [id_cartera] int DEFAULT NULL,
  [id_cliente] int NOT NULL,
  [status] varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  [created_at] datetime2(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  [name] varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  [lastnameP] varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  [lastnameM] varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  [alergias] varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  [tiposangre] varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  [talla] varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  [peso] varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  [precede] varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  [clave] varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  [colegiatura] decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  [seguro] varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  [grado] varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  [nivel] varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  [observaciones] varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  [sexo] varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  [promocion] varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  [estado] varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  [contrato] varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ([id])
) ;
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT  alumnos_  ON;
INSERT INTO alumnos_ VALUES 
(242,"todos mis datos ...",NULL);
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT alumnos_  OFF;
GO
```

Comment: Creo que te falta indicar, de cuanto en cuanto se va incrementar, prueba cambiando tu identity `IDENTITY` por `IDENTITY(1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

La gracia del campo `identity` es que se incrementa automágicamente.

Te está diciendo que no te recibe valores a insertar porque el motor de BD se ocupa de ese campo por su cuenta. A menos que uses la instrucción que te indica, `IDENTiTY_INSERT`, que le dice al motor que permita insertar valores en esa columna ignorando el control que lleva sobre el próximo valor a usar allí.

Entonces, sé más estricto en el INSERT e indícale explícitamente en qué campos quieres insertar los valores que entregas, indicándole que no use estos valores para el campo identity (o lo que sea). Te exige que explícitamente indiques qué campos vas a usar, incluso si prendes el IDENTITY_INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO alumnos_ (id_cartera,id_cliente,...) 
VALUES(242, "otra cosa",...);
```